# Turn on led with button for a period of time and turn off if button is pressed again

Tags: arduino

I cannot figure it out how to write the code for the next situation:
I have a variable stayON = 5000; (5 seconds) that is used to turn on an LED for 5 sec after a button is pressed then turn it over after that time expired. This part I've done it but now I want to break this delay if the button is pressed again. I want to turn OFF the LED if the button is pressed again withing those 5 seconds when the LED is on. It doesn't work with delay() :(

Comment: What kind of hardware are you using? What compiler and tools are you using? What programming language are you using? How can we possibly answer this question without at least some clue about these things?

Comment: it is tagged Arduino, don't you see it?

Comment: @PopescuMarian sometimes people just put an arbitrary tag of arduino. It doesn't mean anything unless the body of the question specifically says 'Arduino'.

Comment: I didn't see it either. In general you can use interrupt service routine for event happening in unknown moment, like user input at arbitrary time. In the code, when you turn your led on, you can initialize a variable and when interrupt occur you can check that variable to confirm that led is on, if it is then you can switch it off. If this is not the case, if you want you can ignore user input or turn the led on.

Comment: [Electrical Engineering Question Checklist](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2990/16051)

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions: You are using Arduino.

Look for the [blink_without_delay](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) example.  It uses the millis value and compares it to the last time the loop was run through to determine if enough time has passed. Translate the following pseudo code to code for your application, and merge it in with the example to do what you need.

Pseudo code:

```
if button pushed and light on {
   Turn light off
}

else if button pushed and light off  {
   Turn light on
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use interrupts. That would probably be the best way because in that time, you can do other things if you wanted too. But a simple way, especially if all you are doing is just controlling this led, is the following

```
for(int x =0;x<500;x++)
{
  delay(10);
  if(digitalRead(button)==ON || x == 499)
    {
       digitalWrite(led)=OFF;
       break;
    }   
}
```

You delay for 10ms, and then check if the button is pressed or if we are at the end of our count, and then turn it off.

You may need to change the "ON" and "OFF" to whatever they should be for your setup up.